# DevExpress Grid: notification for property-of-property works for xaml declared gridcolumn but not for programmatically-added gridcolumn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress-wpf

I have built a UserControl containing a DevExpress GridControl that has its GridColumns added programmatically when a "UCKit" (contains various parameters for the UserControl, including column specs) is bound to the control.  One of the columns is bound to the Count property of an ObservableCollection that is a property of the class making up the GridControl's ItemsSource, and does not respond to PropertyChanged notifications, or even to a brute-force update attempt made by calling grid.RefreshData().  I have written a test program that uses simple GridColumn declarations in xaml, and the Count column works fine, but I can't get the grid whose GridColumns are built in code to update.

Here's the xaml that updates successfully:

```
    <dxg:GridControl Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="griddywiddy2" AutoGenerateColumns="None"
                     Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataColl, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView AllowPerPixelScrolling="True" ShowTotalSummary="True"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Row Name" Width="Auto" FieldName="RowName"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Count" Width="Auto" FieldName="Stringz.Count"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
    </dxg:GridControl>
```

And the xaml + c# code that doesn't (Row Name updates, Count does not):

```
    <dxg:GridControl Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="griddywiddy" AutoGenerateColumns="None"
                     Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataColl, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView AllowPerPixelScrolling="True" ShowTotalSummary="True"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>

    private void InitializeColumns()
    {
        griddywiddy.Columns.Add(
            new DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.GridColumn()
            {
                Header = "Row Name",
                Binding = new Binding("RowName")
                {
                    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
                    Converter = null
                },
                Width = 100
            });
        griddywiddy.Columns.Add(
            new DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.GridColumn()
            {
                Header = "Count",
                Binding = new Binding("Stringz.Count")
                {
                    Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
                    Converter = null
                },
                Width = 100
            });
    }
```

My two methods of updating, both of which work for both xaml-declared columns and for the code-built Row Name column, are (called in button click handlers in my test program):

```
    private void UpdBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        griddywiddy.RefreshData();
        griddywiddy2.RefreshData();
    }

    private void UpdBtn2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyData incer = MyDataColl[0];
        incer.NotifyPropertyChanged("Stringz.Count");
        incer.NotifyPropertyChanged("RowName");
    }
```

I'm truly befuddled as to why this Count property works properly in the xaml case but not the code-built case.  Can anyone advise, please?

Answer (score 0):

It has come to my attention that using Binding = new Binding("Stringz.Count") in the creation of the GridColumn (what I do that fails) is NOT quite equivalent to setting the GridColumn's FieldName="Stringz.Count" (what I do in the xaml, which works.)  So for these "nested" notifications (which call for a complex path), use the FieldName method of specifying the GridColumn.

This solution came courtesy of the folks at DevExpress, btw, big thanks to them!